# Google Api Translate V2, how to use simple url?

Tags: vb.net, api, google-translate

I simple was at:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#WorkingResults

And when using the example of:
h**ps://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world

This also does reach any content:
h**ps://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?

It does not work. File not found. I just tried firefox and webclient in VB.Net with same result.

Please, what is the correct url for translation by Url?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Now I used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512419.aspx
The Microsoft Library. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason accessing the URL using Firefox does not work well.
The same URL using Chrome will show the response in the browser as expected.

You can also try using [google-translate-api-v2-java](http://code.google.com/p/google-translate-api-v2-java/)